# Angular 2 Performance: Is it better to bind with a data member than a function?

Tags: angular, performance, data-binding

I wanted to have some idea about whether binding to data member is better in performance vs binding to a function?

e.g. which of the below statement will have better performance?

**1)**

```
<myComp *ngIf="isThisTrue"></mycomp>
```

where isThisTrue is being set via a method

```
checkIfTrue(data){
       this.isThisTrue = data;
}
```

where this checkfTrue() is being called on receiving an event from an observable.

**or**

**2)**

```
<mycomp *ngIf="seeIfItHasBecomeTrue()"></mycomp>
```

where seeIfItHasBecomeTrue checks to see whether this.isTrue has become true or not.

I clearly feel that binding to data member should be faster, but I am not sure if this will always be faster? or if there are some gray areas? Also, if it is faster then how much?

Comment: Try and put a console.log into seeIfItHasBecomeTrue - I suspect it will be called somewhere between 5 and 30 times. If it is a simple function it doesn't matter but if it is more complex it could turn into something measurable.

Comment: anything unclear about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46903095/2545680)?

Comment: Apologies for the delay.. And thank you for your answer. Could you please help me with full question? I was looking for , if it is always faster and how fast it is.

Comment: @TypeScripter, yes, it will be always faster and I explained why in my answer. How faster depends on a particular machine you're running a code on

Answer (score 10):

If you use the approach `*ngIf="isThisTrue"` the compiler will generate the following `updateRenderer` function:

```
function (_ck, _v) {
    var _co = _v.component;
    var currVal_1 = _co.isThisTrue;   <--- simple member access
    _ck(_v, 5, 0, currVal_1);
}
```

If you use the second approach `*ngIf="seeIfItHasBecomeTrue()"`, the function will look like this:

```
function(_ck,_v) {
    var _co = _v.component;
    var currVal_1 = _co.seeIfItHasBecomeTrue();   <--- function call
    _ck(_v,5,0,currVal_1);
}
```

And the function call is more performance heavy than simple member access.

To learn more about `updateRenderer` function read:

- [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d)

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Comment: You can still see the article on the Internet Archive https://web.archive.org/web/20191114183316/https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d?gi=3c41372d6c8e