# How Angular Change Detection is triggered when you are binding to a function?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

From these two posts:

- [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d)
- [Angular 2 Performance: Is it better to bind with a data member than a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902660/angular-2-performance-is-it-better-to-bind-with-a-data-member-than-a-function/46903095#46903095)

I understand how the DOM updated when the 'Change Detection' has occurred. The thing I do not understand from ["Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular"](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) is how Angular keeps track of what properties have beed used inside the function and therefore when it should run the 'Change Detection'.

Let's assume this is the parent Component view.

```
<child [prop]="func()"></child>
```

where `func()` is

```
func() { return this.parentProp }
```

and `parentProp` has not been used in the template. If and when `parentProp` gets changed by a service, how does the Angular knows that `func()` depends on `parentProp` and therefore should trigger a 'Change Detection' and update the view.

Answer (score 15):

Angular doesn't know or care about the content of the function.

Angular will call `func()` every time change detection runs and compare if the previous result is the same as the current result.

Because calling a function and comparing the result is much more expensive than just comparing the previous value with the current value, it's better to use an event to update a property with the function result and bind the view only to the property, instead of to a function directly.

If the function returns different values on subsequent calls (with the same parameter values) you'll get an exception in development mode like

> the model has changed since it was last checked

Comment: So maybe my question is basic than that. If a component's property which does not appear on the template changes, does the Change Detection runs?

Comment: It's not property changes that cause change detection to run, it's change detection that checks if properties have changed. When change detection is run depends on your settings (for example by setting `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`). Change detection usually happens when an event handler was called and its execution has completed (which is recognized by Angulars zone) or when it's explicitly invoked by `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()`.

Comment: Is it just as expensive to use getter methods instead of an actual function?

Comment: Yes, it's the same, just the syntax is a bit different.