# Prod build issue while checking the length of union type variable having array type in angular html template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, union-types

I am facing an issue while checking the length of union type array, string and number. Sample code of issue while build angular project in prod mode:

**Variable in ts**

```
public developerData: {
    [key: string]: {
        type: 'default';
        data: string | number;
    } | {
        type: 'array',
        data: Array < string | number | boolean >
    }
} = {
    'test': {
        'type': 'array',
        'data': ['1', '2', '3']
    }
};
```

**Html template**

```
<div *ngIf="developerData['test']['type']=='array' && developerData['test']['data'].length >= 0">
   Welcome
</div>
```

**Prod build error**

> Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | number | (string |
> number | boolean)[]'. Property 'length' does not exist on type
> 'number'.

**Software versions**

- Angular: 7.3.5
- TypeScript: 3.1.6
- Node: 10.16.3
- NPM: 6.9.0

Answer (score 0):

While accessing the variable it can either be  a 'string' (or) 'number' (or) 'boolean' at the same time as you have specified using '|' in typescript.

So before accessing 'length' property of the variable add a type check using 'typeof' method in JS.

You can use a validator function in 'tsx' file that checks the type and returns proper validation result and call that in 'ngif'

Comment: Is possible to check without typescript validation. I have to check this within HTML tag.

Comment: You can write nested conditional statements inside ngif if you want, but that would make it  harder to debug. But you can call a validator function in ngIf  like             
<div *ngIf="isValidData()">
   Welcome
</div>

Comment: Can you please share some possible code snippet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674156/angular-ngif-binding-to-function - Refer this question for different Implementations

Comment: I want validation without calling ts methods. While scrolling the page, the method called many times. it may cause page hanging.

Comment: Globals like Window, typeof  are not available within a template as Angular only parses Angular templates and not JS templates. You need to use that within a Component Typescript. But if you want to optimize you can use memoization