# Dynamic css in angular with condition?

Tags: angular

I have this loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of selectedItems; let i = index"  >
                <td [style.padding-left.px]="[ 5 * (i+1)]">{{item.num}}</td>
 </tr>
```

What i want to achive is to add this padding on every item but only if in every item i have same property with same value. For example if i have for all items property `main` that have same value i will add padding if not padding will be always fixed to 5px. Any suggestion?
I manage to add padding like this but without any condition.

Comment: handle the data manipulation in the TS file? loop through all objects in your array and check whatever you like. Then set a property like paddingLeft on the data. in the template you just apply the paddingLeft property as your padding-left value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the condition needs to satisfy all the objects in the array, I'd say it's better to introduce an additional variable that holds the condition as a boolean. You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check the condition.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
export public SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  allMain: boolean = false;  // <-- boolean to hold condition

  ngOnInit() {
    // initialize `selectedItems`
    this.allMain = this.selectedItems.every(item => item['main'] === 'someValue');
  }
}
```

Use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in the template to apply the condition.

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of selectedItems; let i = index">
  <td [style.padding-left.px]="allMain ? [5 * (i+1)] : 5">{{item.num}}</td>
</tr>
```

Note:

1. I haven't checked the styling part. But the gist of it is to use the ternary operator.
2. Ideal solution here would be to write a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be

1. Have a method in your .ts file that checks if the value of the item is the same in the list
2. Create a new css class that adds the padding
3. Use ngClass to add the css class if the condition of the method is true.

Eg.
.html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of selectedItems; let i = index"  >
                    <td [ngClass]="isDuplicate(item) ? 'p-5' :''">
                     {{item.num}}</td>
     </tr>
```

.css

```
    .p-5{
         padding-left: 5px;
        }
```

.ts

```
   isDuplicate(item): boolean {
   return this.selectedItems.filter(x => x.num === item.num).length > 1;
 }
```

Comment: Binding a function to a directive with default change detection strategy would trigger the function for each change detection cycle. Plug in a `console.log` in the function to check the frequency of triggers. It could lead to potential performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Handle logic in ts file and return padding values only

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of selectedItems; let i = index"  >
                <td [style.padding-left]="setpadding(item,i)">{{item.num}}</td>
</tr>
```

**TS:-**

```
setpadding(item:any,index:nuber):string{
   if(your condition){
     //your condition

     return `10px`;   //your padding based on condition
   }
  else{
    //default
   return `5px`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment on @IfesinachiBryan's answer.

Comment: I heard writing same ternary logic in ts file & returning value, and html binding are same .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674156/angular-ngif-binding-to-function

Comment: The answer speaks about getting a single variable from the controller using a getter. It's not the same as running a condition (in your ansswer: `if (your condition)`) for each CD cycle. What do you think the `your condition` could look like in your answer?

Comment: it adds more customization being able to access individual array object and compare keys or add any business logic then render as needed. that's all. Though for simple thing as style.padding-left I think your answer checks out.