# Angular 5: calling method from html

Tags: angular

I am not getting why it is not working.

I am trying to show Login/Logout link based on condtion by calling a method from html. in console I can see it is returning "true", but it never changes the link to "Logout". it is always "Login" on the screen

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" [hidden]="!authenticated()">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Welcome, {{user}}!
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" [hidden]="authenticated()">
        <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

component.ts

```js
authenticated() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('authenticated'));
    if(localStorage.getItem('authenticated') === 'true') {
        console.log("YES");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("NO");
        return false;    
    }
}
```

Before clicking on Login link
[image]

After click on Login
[image]

After entering correct username/password (Her you can see in console it returns true)
[image]

Comment: Try `*ngIf` instead of `hidden` directive. If you want `hidden` return `null` instead of `false`.

Comment: But if you see the console log, it satisfies the condition anf prints "YES", that means it returns string.

Comment: @ritaj: any code example please, syntax...

Comment: Just replace `[hidden]` with `*ngIf`, which you should be using anyway. `*ngIf="!authenticated()"`

Comment: how does that works? I mean how it will know it will be hidden or not

Comment: It's completely the same as your example. Let me write an anwer.

Comment: I tried that, but now I can't see either Login or Logout

Comment: Did you forget to put the exclamaton mark? `!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should not call a function with `*ngIf` directive, as it will run with every change detection. This can lead to performance overhead. Either use a variable or convert your method into a getter property e.g.

```js
get authenticated(): boolean {
    return localStorage.getItem('authenticated') === true;
}
```

Secondly, use `*ngIf` instead of `[hidden]`:

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngIf="authenticated">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Welcome, {{user}}!
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngIf="!authenticated">
        <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm unable to see the performance advantage of using a getter property over a function. Why is this better?

Comment: @david-walschots maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46903095/1791913

Comment: Yes. I understand that a function call has a certain overhead (even though that overhead is probably very small when the function doesn't do much). However, a getter property is in fact nothing more than a function, which is why I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `hidden` directive with `*ngIf` directive.

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngIf="!authenticated()">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Welcome, {{user}}!
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngIf="authenticated()">
        <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It's functinally the same, but `ng-if` directive remove the element from DOM, and `hidden` attribute just hides it.

Another solution is to change your method to this:

```js
authenticated() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('authenticated'));
    if(localStorage.getItem('authenticated') === 'true') {
        console.log("YES");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("NO");
        return null;    
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, After I make that change, I can't see either Login or Logout. I think something else is wrong...

Comment: Something else is wrong right now, you should see one of them for sure. Can you make a working example on StackBlitz?

Comment: Here is my code: <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngIf="!authenticated()">                 </li>   <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngIf="authenticated()">   </li

Comment: As it is integrated with spring, database, I am not sure how I can create a stackblitz

Comment: Well nothing here is connected to the DB, even your `authenticated` method doesn't talk to the back end. You can mock the needed data. But the main point is just making you rewrite the code, which sometimes helps in finding the mistake by itself.

Comment: And if you can reproduce the error, I will have much easier time finding it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170103/discussion-between-ritaj-and-sk).

Comment: I am a stupid. both your and my code is fine. But I did a mistake. If oyu see my code, the Logout link is in a dropdown. That is why it is not showing up...

Comment: Haha. Well, happens to everybody! But do learn to use `*ngIf` (and what @Faisal said), so the time was not wasted!